# How do I open .mdf file & .ldf file in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to sql. My client has given me one .mdf file & one *ldf file. I have Microsoft SQL Server Management studio 2018 installed in my client system. Server management studio is asking for server name & windows authentication to connect. I don't have any server assigned to me. Can you please suggest me the steps to connect server management studio?

Comment: Install Microsoft SQL Server, connect to the installed server with Microsoft SQL Server Management studio 2018, attach the db (mdf-file). Enjoy

Comment: SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) doesn't host databases, it's just a management application that connects to SQL Server instances where the databases are hosted. You'll need access to an SQL Server instance, perhaps install one, to which you can attach the .mdf and .ldf files. Tip: find out from your client which version of SQL Server the .mdf and .ldf files came from - you'll need a SQL Server version that matches, or is newer, than what they were using.

Comment: `My client has given me one .mdf file & one *ldf file.` SQL Server isn't a file-based database like SQLite or Access. It's a database server like Oracle, DB2, MySQL, PostgreSQL. You can't just copy the data and transaction log. *After* you install SQL Server on your machine you can try attaching those files. This is done using SQL commands and can be done with any client application, even from the command line. Management applications like SQL Server Management Studio allow you to do this from a UI which is a *lot* easier

Comment: Hey @Sergey, OP basically asks, "how do I connect and attach an mdf file" and you answer "just install connect and attach mdf file, enjoy". This is not an answer. You are just repeating the question.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, sounds like you're onto something. Would you consider creating an answer for this question?